# React + Polymer: Pass through callback from React into Polymer component

Tags: reactjs, polymer, web-component

I am struggling to pass in functions as properties into Polymer components. I managed to get it working when doing so from another Polymer component by using one way data binding, but when I am loading my Polymer component within a React project and try to pass in a function for the property it comes through as a string.

Simplified version of Polymer component:

```
export class PolymerButton extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
    <div>
      [[text]]
    </div>
  `;
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      text: { type: String },
      clickHandler: {
        type: Function,
        value: null
      },
      disabled: { type: Boolean }
    };
  }

  ready() {
    super.ready();
    this.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.onButtonClick(e));
  }

  onButtonClick(e) {
    if (!this.disabled) {
      this.clickHandler(e);
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('ppp-button', PolymerButton);
```

How I managed to use it in another Polymer component:

```
<ppp-button text="Click me" click-handler="[[_clickCallback]]"></ppp-button>
```

How I am trying to use it in React:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="export-btn">
            <ppp-button text="Export" click-handler={this.exportReport} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I click the button, the value of the clickHandler property will be the string `"{this.exportReport}"`.

The Polymer component is loading fine, it is just this click handler part that works. I have tried various syntax with no luck. I am using Polymer 3 and React 15, and I am loading the `react-polymer` library within my React component.

Comment: I never used `polymer-react`, but if it's this one here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-polymer it says there that it "**now** supports Polymer 2.0".. nothing about Polymer 3..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you cannot directly call the functions of the Polymer based on what I have tried. But I have been able to use Polymer Element or a webcomponent with React 16. The implementation would be, install the webcomponent which you are planning to use and import that inside the react component where the webcomponent will be used.

`import '@vaadin/vaadin-date-picker';`

Then inside your component under `render` function:

`<div >
    <vaadin-date-picker label="When were you born?" ref="dobRef"></vaadin-date-picker>
</div>`

I have used ref here which is a way to get a hold of the DOM and to pass the value. Also, you will have to use `componentDidMount` :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.refs.dobRef.addEventListener('change', e=> {
    console.log('componentDidMount', e.target.value);
  })
}
```

The event listener would vary based on the event that you want to handle.